# UV Texture Font

Tags: texturing, uv

I've got a simple render of a keyboard and am wanting to add the alphas/modifiers (CTRL/SHIFT etc.) to the render.

I do the following:
-> UV Unwrap the 'tops' of my caps
-> Export the mapping to *.png, edit the *.png and add the wording, for example 'SHIFT'
-> Create an image texture (im using Cycles render)
-> Render the image

I end up with 'blurry' text:

[image]

Please see here for more info:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?386617-UV-Texture-Font

Comment: What is the nodes setup used, particulalry mask that you made to make letters appear ?

Comment: I'll try get the formatting right:
Color
Linear
Flat
Repeat
Single Image
UV Map
Unchecked From Dupli
UVMap